# SwiftUI view, initialize closure with struct member says >'self' used before all stored properties are initialized<

Tags: swift, initialization, swiftui, closures

I want to initialize an onTap closure where a method from viewmodel should be called. This function will be passed to another class which will call it. I couldn't figure out how to initialized it because it does not let me to use self and if i try to use weak reference to the viewmodel it says:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
> here is the code:

```
typealias OnTabBarTap = (Tab) -> Void
struct TabScreenView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Tab = .BROWSE
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TabScreenViewModel
    var onTabItemTap: OnTabBarTap

    init(currentSelectedTab: Tab) {
        viewModel = TabScreenViewModel(
                input: TabScreenInput(
                    onStart: PassthroughSubject(),
                    onTabClick: PassthroughSubject()
                )
        )
        onTabItemTap = {
            [viewModel](tab: Tab) -> Void in
            viewModel.input.onTabClick.send(tab)
        }
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                CurrentView(currentView: $selectedTab)
                BottomTabBarView(tabs: $viewModel.tabs, onTap: onTabItemTap)
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .onAppear{
                self.viewModel.input.onStart.send(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in onTabItemTap in your init, you are accessing viewModel before the init has finished which you cannot do. You could use a computed property for onTabItemTap that is based off of the viewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (viewModel is reference type, so you can manipulate with it as temporary variable)

```
init(currentSelectedTab: Tab) {
    let vm = TabScreenViewModel(
            input: TabScreenInput(
                onStart: PassthroughSubject(),
                onTabClick: PassthroughSubject()
            )
    )
    self.viewModel = vm
    onTabItemTap = {
        [vm](tab: Tab) -> Void in
        vm.input.onTabClick.send(tab)
    }
}
```